# Равномерное увеличение ширины элемента

Tags: html, jquery

Есть следующий код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.value').width() < 95) {
      $('.value').width($('.value').width() + 5 + '%');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.bar {
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
  }

  .value {
    width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="value"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы ширина каждый раз увеличивалась на 5%, но она увеличивается неравномерно. Подскажите как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    let width = parseInt($('.value')[0].style.width || '0%')
    if(width < 95)
      $('.value').width(5+width + '%')
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.value {
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="value"></div>
</div>
```